# How to update hosts file on google cloud vm

Tags: google-compute-engine

Can anyone help me in updating the hosts file on google cloud vm ? I tried adding alias and bouncing the server but I dont see the update.

Here is what I have

```
10.12.0.2 gapp.c.flash-arbor-123843.internal gapp # Added by Google
```

I'm trying to update it to below but gets reset to above line after restarting the server.

```
10.12.0.2 gapp.c.flash-arbor-123843.internal gapp iam.sandbox.com# Added by Google
```

Thanks in advance !!

OS is RHEL v7

Comment: This video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OcDTDL-I8-Q) has the information to change the hostname of GCE instance which might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Answer

Step 1: Change Hostname

```
# nano /etc/sysconfig/network
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=your.hostname.com
```

Step 2: Create crontab auto set Hostname

```
# crontab -e
@reboot hostname="your.hostname.com"; sed -i "s/.*Google.*//" /etc/hosts; hostname "$hostname"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add the host iam.sandbox.com to a new line with the same ip, before the google entry

if you have more instances in your project, you will need to update the host file on each instance with the records in order to be able to resolve them.

I would try to avoid any network/host related editing on gce instance.

Answer (score 0):

in order to change the hostname on GCE, you have to use meta-data and cronjob @reboot.

[root@vmx-instance-1 ~]# crontab -l
@reboot sleep 100;hostname $(curl --silent "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/hostname" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")
[root@vmx-instance-1 ~]#

Also you have to add a meta-data on instance level 
hostname  value=FQDN